# catching specific error in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, global-asax

I am using Application_Error event in global asax to catch errors and write them to a file. I can see the specific exception in the webpage, but in the log file all I see is a generic error like this:

```
Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.review_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\...\ff7eee7c\ff24ade1\App_Web_tddyd4bt.3.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

How can I write the errors as I see in the yellow page to log file instead of this generic error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Is this what you looking for?*

```
 Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();    
 String ExceptionMessage = (ex.InnerException != null) ? ex.InnerException.Message : ex.Message;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Global.asax, find the Application_Error method and add the following:

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
        LogHelper.WriteLog(ex);
    }
```

You need to create a class to write the log..

```
public class LogHelper
{
    public static void WriteLog(Exception exception)
    {
       //write to text file the exception.Message ...
    }
}
```